# Maven Test Scope

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, slf4j, logback

If I have one project of mine myproject1 that has the following depenedencies:

```
        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And i include myproject1 in myproject2 like so:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Android Logging-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tony19</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-android-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tony19</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-android-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1-2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am still seeing logback classes being included in myproject2. My understanding is that the test scope should prevent those jars from bleeding into parent projects. Am I misunderstanding something? I am currently running into compilation issues as my parent project relies on logback-android and so I have multiple classes with the same name e.g. `ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude transitive dependencies from `myproject1` and you have two options here.

**Optional dependency**. Mark `logback-core` in `myproject1` as optional:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

**Excluded dependency**. Exclude `logback-core` when including `myproject1`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Also I think if you run build with tests off (`-Dmaven.test.skip=true`) `logback-core` will not be included anyway.

Run `mvn dependency:tree` to see origin of your dependencies and their scope.

Comment: Is this how most open source projects do it? It seems weird that there is no a better method to have a logging class for testing, but you do no want it in the final package.

Comment: dependencies with test scope are not included in packaging unless you explicitly include them, what is your packaging for myproject2?

Comment: Its not currently set so it defaults to jar I suppose.

Comment: in this case dependencies are only used for compiling, packaging will use resources defined in current project only

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I definitely have the scopes set as test, and when I run `mvn clean install` I still have the logback jars in my other project. Excluding them does prevent this though. Do I need the test scope AND the optional flag?

Comment: Your other project might have different packaging, anyway you can check where they come from using `mvn dependency:tree` as mentioned above